# CRON job executing PHP cannot require another file

Tags: php, cron, require

I have a cron job that runs a php file. Within the php file it requires another file. For other php files run by cron and I do the same require file, it works just file. I've changed permissions on all files involved to 777 (for testing) and the problem still occurs. When I execute the file from the command line, it runs just fine.

**Why is the file not allowed permission for this 1 php file?**

Here is the error I receive from the cron:

```
[Fri Mar 29 00:05:01 2013] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /home/rpn/public_html/admin/admin_functions.php - Permission denied (pid 29776)
PHP Warning:  require(/home/rpn/public_html/admin/admin_functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/rp/public_html/cron/cron-boxscores.php on line 6

Warning: require(/home/rpn/public_html/admin/admin_functions.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/rp/public_html/cron/cron-boxscores.php on line 6
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/rpn/public_html/admin/admin_functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/rp/php') in /home/rp/public_html/cron/cron-scrape-boxscores.php on line 6

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/rpn/public_html/admin/admin_functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/rp/php') in /home/rp/public_html/cron/cron-boxscores.php on line 6
```

Here is line 6:

```
require('/home/rpn/public_html/admin/admin_functions.php');
```

Here is the directory showing the file and permissions settings:

```
root@host [/home/rpn/public_html/admin]# ls -l admin*
-rw-r--r-- 1 nobody nobody 19022 Mar  8 14:18 admin_functions.php
```

nobody:nobody is what Apache is set to run under.

Comment: Which account is the cron job running as and what are the permissions on `/home/rpn` and `/home/rpn/public_html`?

Comment: @webbiedave
drwx--x--x  9 rpn    rpn        4096 Feb 15 14:21 rpn/
drwxr-x---  3 nobody nobody 4096 Mar 11 12:09 public_html/
I don't know what you mean by "Which account is the cron job running as". It should be the default cron permission. I don't know how to find that out.

Comment: @webbiedave I've changed the permissions on the public_html to 755.  We'll see tonight if that alone can fix it. The cron job is being executed by cPanel and I think the account is "rp".

Comment: @webbiedave I've also added the user rp to the group nobody.